# OOP Pygame platform game: controlling and moving a square on a screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, pygame

```
import pygame
import random
import math
import sys

screenWidth = 1200
screenHeight = 600

class Hero:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.width = 30
        self.height = 30
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)
        self.dirX = 0
        self.dirY = 0

    def move(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.dirX = 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.dirX = -1

    def draw(self, display):
        x = self.pos[0]
        y = self.pos[1]
        pygame.draw.rect(display, self.color, (x + self.dirX, y + self.dirY, self.width, self.height))
        print(self.pos, self.dirX, self.dirY)
    
    def jump(self):
        pass


    def die(self):
        pass


class Enemy:
    pass

class Background:
    pass

class Obstacles:
    pass

class Camera:
    pass

def score():
    pass

def create(w, h):
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
    display.fill((255, 255, 255))
    #create background
    #create Obstacles
    #create Hero
    heroOne = Hero([150, 450])
    heroOne.move()
    heroOne.draw(display)
    #create Enemy
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    running = True
    while running:

        clock.tick(300)

        create(screenWidth, screenHeight)

main()
```

Hi, I am making an OOP Game using Pygame in which a square would be controlled by the user and move along a floor, jump over obstacles and other enemy squares.

The way I want it to work:
When I press K_LEFT, `dirX = 1` it will add to the x-coordinate of the `pos` and hence the x-position of the square will be updated and the square will begin to slide towards the right. When I press `dir = -1`and square will move to the left.

The way it is working:
No

I think the problem is the `pos` of the main cube does not seem to update and the `dirX` updates from `0` to `1` and goes back to `0`.

I guess changing the values of the variables under the `__init__()` function is done as I am doing it or perhaps it is completely wrong.

Is this any way to make my code work the way I am trying to do it or is it completely a wrong way and there is some other way?

I am learning OOP and python, any additional advice or links regarding the best practices, relating to this code, would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you've to invoke `move` in the main application loop:

```py
def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    heroOne = Hero([150, 450])
    running = True
    while running:
        clock.tick(300)

        display.fill((255, 255, 255))
        heroOne.move()
        heroOne.draw(display)
        pygame.display.update()
```

You have to change the position of the player by `self.dirX` and `self.dirY`, in every frame:

```py
class Hero:
    # [...]

    def move(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.dirX = 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.dirX = -1

        new_x = self.pos[0] + self.dirX
        new_y = self.pos[1] + self.dirY
        self.pos = [new_x , new_y]

    def draw(self, display):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, self.color, (*self.pos, self.width, self.height))
```

If you wan to move the rectangle, just when a key is pressed, then I recommend to use [`pygame.key.get_pressed`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) rather than the `KEYDOWN` event:

```py
class Hero:
    # [...]

    def move(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.pos[0] -= 1 
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.pos[0] += 1
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.pos[1] -= 1 
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.pos[1] += 1
```

---

Complete code:

```py
import pygame
import random
import math
import sys

screenWidth = 1200
screenHeight = 600

class Hero:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
        self.width = 30
        self.height = 30
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)
        self.dirX = 0
        self.dirY = 0

    def move(self, events):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.pos[0] -= 1 
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.pos[0] += 1
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.pos[1] -= 1 
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.pos[1] += 1

    def draw(self, display):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, self.color, (*self.pos, self.width, self.height))
    
    def jump(self):
        pass


    def die(self):
        pass


class Enemy:
    pass

class Background:
    pass

class Obstacles:
    pass

class Camera:
    pass

def score():
    pass


def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth, screenHeight))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    heroOne = Hero([150, 450])
    running = True
    while running:
        clock.tick(300)
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        heroOne.move(events)

        display.fill((255, 255, 255))
        heroOne.draw(display)
        pygame.display.update()   

main()
```

Comment: Works amazingly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mhf Thank you. You're welcoem.

Answer (score 1):

In your `create` function you are creating new instance of the `Hero` each time its being called.

Instead, init heroOne in the `main`, and pass it as an argument so you can use it:

```
def main():
    pygame.init()
    heroOne = Hero([150, 450])
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    running = True
    while running:

        clock.tick(30)

        create(screenWidth, screenHeight, heroOne)
```

Also add increment in the `move` method:

```
self.dirX += 1
```

and:

```
self.dirX -= 1
```

Now the object will move `by one` on each keypress.

And if you want continuous movement you should put some `flag`, e.g. if it is `True` `+=1` and "False" `-=1` and key presses will change the `flag` state.